# Disable drag bubbling for nested sortable items in jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Given a set of sortable/draggable containers, each of which contains draggable/sortable list items, how can list items be optionally non-sortable without allowing the drag event(s) to bubble up to the parent container?

In the example below, if you drag on 'Item 3 (Disabled)', the parent container becomes the drag target. It should still be draggable, but only outside of the inner items.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.sortable').sortable({
      items: '.draggable'
    });
    $('.sortable').disableSelection();
  });
</script>

<ul class="sortable outer">
  <li class="outer-item draggable">
    <ul class="sortable">
      <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 1</li>
      <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 2</li>
      <li class="inner-item"></span>Item 3 (Disabled)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="outer-item draggable">
    <ul class="sortable">
      <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 4</li>
      <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 5</li>
      <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/jneander/full/NRNZqL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop the dragging event for non-sortable element you may disable the items not included:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.sortable').sortable({
    items: '.draggable'
  });
  $('li:not(".draggable")').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.outer {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
}

.outer-item {
  background: #f9f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #e1c5c5;
  padding: 1em;
}

.outer-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.inner-item {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.inner-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable outer">
    <li class="outer-item draggable">
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 1</li>
            <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 2</li>
            <li class="inner-item"></span>Item 3 (Disabled)</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="outer-item draggable">
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 4</li>
            <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 5</li>
            <li class="inner-item draggable"></span>Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This has the side effect of slight nudges to the positions of elements, as the dragging occurs momentarily before stopping.

Comment: It also does weird things with DOM positioning, possibly due to some uncleaned state internally.

Comment: With this update, there is behaviorally no change from the original code. Disabling the relevant elements, whether programmatically or statically, appears to have no effect. The parent is still receiving the drag event through the disabled element.

Comment: The updated snippet, with one minor edit, gets the job done. Thank you so much for your efforts!